# Lightning Component OR operator only evaluating first two parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Running into the issue and wondered if I am doing something wrong, have incorrect expectations, etc.

When using the `or` operator in a lightning component (including lightning out) to evaluate values in either an `if` statement or `isTrue` property I am observing that if you have more than two variables the or is not evaluated correctly.

Take the below example that illustrates this:

```
<aura:component description="myORExample" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:if isTrue="{!or(false,false,true)}">
        <p>Three Or Evaluations with last true</p>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!or(true,false,false)}">
        <p>Three Or Evaluations with first true</p>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!or(false,true,false)}">
        <p>Three Or Evaluations with second true</p>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!or(false,true)}">
        <p>Two Or Evaluations with one true</p>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

[image]

Placing this on a page layout you will see that the first example is evaluated to false and thus does not display. It clearly should evaluate to true as the third value is `true`.

Seems that only the first two variables are evaluated in the `or` operator.

Bug or working a designed?

Comment: Well this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) says "Returns true if either one of the arguments is true"; "either" implies only 2 to me (vs "any").

Comment: My search is failing lately....thank for the dupe @sfdcfox

Answer (score 5):

You can use `||` in place of the `OR()` operation. So your code would look like the below code:

```
<aura:component description="myORExample" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:if isTrue="{!false || false || true}">
    <p>Three Or Evaluations with last true</p>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!true || false || false}">
    <p>Three Or Evaluations with first true</p>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!false || true || false}">
    <p>Three Or Evaluations with second true</p>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!false || true}">
    <p>Two Or Evaluations with one true</p>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: This is indeed the workaround that I am using so appreciate your confirmation. Upvoting but not accepting as the question was about why OR was not working. The answer is important however, just wanted to explain my thoughts....

Comment: This also applies to the and() operator. If  your  evaluating in markup you must escape the && as &amp;&amp;.

eg. isTrue="{var1 &amp;&amp; var2 &amp;&amp; var3}"

Comment: kudos Dan!! great workaround