# how can we check 3 condition using aura:if

Tags: lightning-experience, aura-if

i have a radiobutton group which contains daily, weekly and monthly. when i choose daily radio option its showing picklist, when i choose weekly its showing picklist but when i select monthly radio option nothing is showing.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.radioOpValue == 'Daily',v.radioOpValue == 'Weekly',v.radioOpValue == 'Monthly')}">

<lightning:select name="selectDaily" label="Time"  class="dropdown_container">
      <option value="--None--">--None--</option>
      <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
      <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
 </lightning:select>
</<aura:if>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In aura:if attribute, when you are using OR keyword, then it only evaluate first two condition as per this [idea](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178113/lightning-component-or-operator-only-evaluating-first-two-parameters/178119). You can convert or to || operator, and it will work fine. Try this -

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! (v.radioOpValue == 'Daily' || v.radioOpValue == 'Weekly' || v.radioOpValue == 'Monthly')}">
```